# How to run Unison through automator?

Tags: terminal, automator, macos

I like to set up unison through Automator to run in the background to sync up two of my folders in a dropbox-like manner, but Automator apparently fails to run unison through shell script. I have tried both the regular terminal command:

```
unison /folder1 /folder2
```

and the full path for unison:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/unison/2.40.102/bin/unison /folder1 /folder2
```

Comment: How does Automator fail? Does it bring up an error message?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to run it through Apple Script and iTerm.

```
tell application "iTerm"
    make new terminal
    tell the current terminal
        activate current session

        launch session "Default Session"
        tell the last session
            write text "unison /folder1 /folder2"
        end tell
        terminate the last session

    end tell
end tell
```

Remember to double forward slash for space in the path in your folder roots.

I am not sure how to run it in the background. This script will bring the iTerm to focus.